# How to join table and CTE using primary key

Tags: sql, join, common-table-expression

I am confused about how to fix it; can anyone help me?

```
with table_harga_barang as
(
    select harga
    from `kimia.penjualan` pen
    where id_barang >= 'BRG0001' 
      and id_barang <= 'BRG0010'
)
select 
    table_harga_barang as harga_barang, 
    bar.nama_barang, bar.tipe, bar.lini 
from 
    table_harga_barang
inner join 
    `kimia.barang` bar on bar.kode_barang = pen.id_barang;
```

How can I fix 'on'?

I already tried but I don't know how I can join on the primary key

Comment: i would suggest you to do a very simple step: check the output of your cte and think about id_barang and pen.

Comment: The ON clause can only have conditions referencing table_harga_barang and bar. Where did you find pen?

Comment: Primary key or not, doesn't matter. A JOIN doesn't need to know such information.

Answer (score 0):

The alias 'pen' you used inside the CTE remains in the CTE (not recognised by the the 'calling/main' query (the bottom part). To make it work you have to select pen.id_barang from the CTE, and use that in the join. Also, the 'caller/main' query (not being aware of the alias 'pen') can assign a new alias to the CTE (it can even be 'pen' again).

Also you are using the table name as a  column in `SELECT ...table_harga_barang as harga_barang`, I presume you wanted to retrieve harga here.

```
with table_harga_barang as
(
    select id_barang
         , harga
    from `kimia.penjualan` pen
    where id_barang >= 'BRG0001' 
      and id_barang <= 'BRG0010'
)
select 
    pen.harga as harga_barang, 
    bar.nama_barang, bar.tipe, bar.lini 
from 
    table_harga_barang pen
inner join 
    `kimia.barang` bar on bar.kode_barang = pen.id_barang;
```

There is not much benefit to using a CTE in this context (other than, perhaps, you wanted to emphasize `id_barang >= 'BRG0001' and id_barang <= 'BRG0010'` criteria towards the top of the query?